# For every number there is a graph with perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

For every k>=3 integer construct a graph, which have k different perfect matching. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Proper formatting is expected; for basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Consider a complete bipartite graph with $k$ vertices in each partite set. It has $k!$ different matchings. So how might you pare that down?